# Function in Python list comprehension, don't eval twice

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm composing a Python list from an input list run through a transforming function. I would like to include only those items in the output list for which the result isn't `None`. This works:

```py
def transform(n):
    # expensive irl, so don't execute twice
    return None if n == 2 else n**2


a = [1, 2, 3]

lst = []
for n in a:
    t = transform(n)
    if t is not None:
        lst.append(t)

print(lst)
```

```
[1, 9]
```

I have a hunch that this can be simplified with a comprehension. However, the straighforward solution

```py
def transform(n):
    return None if n == 2 else n**2


a = [1, 2, 3]
lst = [transform(n) for n in a if transform(n) is not None]

print(lst)
```

is no good since `transform()` is applied twice to each entry. Any way around this?

Comment: If you have Python 3.8 or later, you might be able to use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to save the result of the function call.

Comment: Another option is to use `@functools.lru_cache`

Comment: You could just build a generator to get the result of `transform` and use `filter` to remove `None` values, something like `lst = list(filter(None, map(transform, a)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `:=` operator for python >=3.8.

```py
lst = [t for n in a if (t:= transform(n)) is not None]
```

Answer (score 4):

If not able/don't want to use walrus operator, one can use [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to cache the result from calling the function and avoid calling it twice

```
import functools

eggs = [2, 4, 5, 3, 2]

@functools.lru_cache
def spam(foo):
    print(foo) # to demonstrate each call
    return None if foo % 2 else foo

print([spam(n) for n in eggs if spam(n) is not None])
```

output

```
2
4
5
3
[2, 4, 2]
```

**Compared with walrus operator ([currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75110079/4046632)) this will be the better option if there are duplicate values in the input list**, i.e. walrus operator will always run the function once per element in the input list. Note, you may combine `finctools.lru_cache` with walrus operator, e.g. for readability.

```
eggs = [2, 4, 5, 3, 2]

def spam(foo):
    print(foo) # to demonstrate each call
    return None if foo % 2 else foo

print([bar for n in eggs if (bar:=spam(n)) is not None])
```

output

```
2
4
5
3
2
[2, 4, 2]
```